# Read Json to object

Tags: c++, nlohmann-json

I am currently trying to read json file into an object. The version of nlohmann-json that I am using is 3.7.3. I followed the example code in that documentation that goes like this

```
// read a JSON file
std::ifstream i("file.json");
json j;
i >> j;
```

My implementation for this was to  have a simple  function that returns a json object, so simply:

```
nlohmann::json UTSF::readJSONFile(std::string filename)
{ 
       std::ifstream i("file.json");
       json j;
       i >> j;
       return j;
}
```

I get the following error `no operator ">>" matches these operands operand types are: json >> std::ifstream`

So I did some investigating that this way of doing it is no longer used in version 3.7.3. I also looked into using `json.parse` and did not work as well.

What is the most update way to do this for nlohmann-jsonversion 3.7.3 ?
I'm also having similar issues with writing json to file as well

This is a minimal reproducible example I wrote that gives me the same error;

```
#include <iostream>
#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>
#include <fstream>
using json = nlohmann::json;

nlohmann::json readJSONFile(std::string filename)
{
    std::ifstream i(filename);
    json j;
    i >> j;
    return j;
}

int main()
{
    nlohmann::json x;
    x = readJSONFile("file.json");
    std::cout << x.dump(4) << std::endl;
}
```

[image: Error list]

Comment: This should still work with the current release: [documentation](https://github.com/nlohmann/json/blob/develop/README.md#tofrom-streams-eg-files-string-streams). Please post a [mre] with the full code and full error message

Comment: @AlanBirtles The function is the minimal reproducible example. I use unit tests to test the code because it's part of bigger solution already.

Comment: From the part of the message you have given it looks like you're doing `j >> i` instead of `i >> j`

Comment: I notice that you haven't fully qualified `nlohmann::json` in your function body.  Did you do a `using namespace nlohmann;` or do you have some other `json` type coming from somewhere else?

Comment: It's not reproducible though, I can't paste the code into a compiler and get the same error message

Comment: Can you show a compilable example that shows the error.

Comment: @AlanBirtles I updated the question

Comment: Your program is missing `#include <fstream>`. After adding that, [it compiles just fine using nlohmann-json 3.1.2](https://wandbox.org/permlink/zj3GTOjqejY8RJ8Y). Please note that your claimed error message `no operator ">>" matches these operands operand types are: json >> std::ifstream` has the order of the arguments reversed with regard to your code. I am led to believe you have not tried to run the code you've posted.

Comment: You need to include `fstream`, if you look in the full error output there's probably a complaint that `ifstream` isn't a complete type

Comment: @alterigel @Alan Birtles. I did have `#include <fstream>` in my my minimal reproducible example I some how forgot to add to the posted question. Strangely enough that still doesn't work. Should I just use a older version of nlohmann-json instead of version 3.7.3?

Comment: It's nothing to do with the version, post a [mre]  with the full error output and we might be able to help

Comment: Along with the code and output, what compiler, compiler version, and compiler flags are you using?

Comment: @AlanBirtles I posted the error list

Comment: I just tried running your exact code on Visual Studio 2019 using nlohmann::json 3.7.3, and it compiled without errors. I can't reproduce your problem at all.

Comment: Please try creating an empty Visual Studio project, adding only a freshly-downloaded json.hpp header file and your main source file, and seeing what happens.

Comment: Please post the compiler output text not a screenshot of the error list

Answer (score 0):

For nlohmann i use this simple function

```
#include <nlohmann/json.hpp>

....

nlohmann::json ReadJsonFromFile(std::string file_name) {

    try {
        return nlohmann::json::parse(std::ifstream{file_name, std::ios::in});
    } catch (nlohmann::json::parse_error& e) {
        std::cerr << "JSON parse exception : " << e.what() << std::endl;
    } catch (std::ifstream::failure& e) {
        std::cerr << "Stream exception : " << e.what() << std::endl;
    } catch (std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << "Exception : " << e.what() << std::endl;
    } catch (...) {
        std::cerr << "Unk error" << std::endl;
    }

    return {};
}
```

Comment: Thanks, a similar error occurs `no operator matches these operands            operand types are: std::istream >> nlohmann::json`. Can I just ignore this?

Comment: @alongtest12 add #include <nlohmann/json.hpp> and check successful link library

Comment: Yeah everything is linked and I have the include. I already use  nlohmann::json in another function to create a json object, But for some reason trying to read the file I'm stumped with this error.

Comment: This is no different to the original code just unnecessarily complicated

Comment: @AlanBirtles upd ans - please check

Comment: I still don't think this will solve the op's problem

Comment: @alongtest12 try this